# SSIS Import from Multiple Data Sources

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, teradata

I have a little bit of a challenge.  I have to consolidate some data that is coming from three different databases (Oracle, SQL Server, and Teradata).

How can I retrieve the data from TeraData and SQL Server based on the retrieve from Oracle?

For instance, Oracle has the sales information, TeraData has the client information, and SQL Server has the employee information.

I pull the list of sales from Oracle which has a list of client IDs and want to limit the TeraData pull based on those client IDs.

The clients then have an Employee identifier that ties to SQL Server.

I can connect to each individually but would like to limit the pulls from each.

Oracle returns about 3,000 rows while TeraData by itself returns 400,000 rows.  The Oracle to TeraData is a many to 1 relationship (many oracle records to 1 TeraData record).

I have tried using the data source merge option but it runs each data source individually then merges them which ends up drastically increasing the amount of processing time due to the amount of records in TeraData.

Your assistance is appreciated.   Thanks.

Comment: The most efficient approach would be to copy the smallest amount of records locally to the server with the largest amount of records then joining to decide what to send back.

I would expect you would have far more sales records (in Oracle) than client records (in Teradata) are you sure you've got that the right way around?

Is the intention of this for reporting (in which case I suggest you look into star schemas, ETL etc.) or is it for managing master data?

Comment: @ElectricLlama I do not have write access to either server.  Is there a way to pull the data from one as a temp table in the other?

Comment: You pass over some SQL with an enormous IN string if you though it would reduce the record count: `SELECT Sales.* FROM Teradata.Sales WHERE ClientID IN (<pre-generated in-list>)` You'd need to pre generate a static SQL string from something else before running against Teradata. You might run into SQL length issues if it's large.

Comment: If you don't have write access, where are you pushing the final data to?

Comment: @ElectricLlama  It pulls the data from TeraData and Oracle and SQL Server and exports to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You pass over some SQL with an enormous IN string if you though it would reduce the record count: SELECT Sales.* FROM Teradata.Sales WHERE ClientID IN () You'd need to pre generate a static SQL string from something else before running against Teradata. You might run into SQL length issues if it's large.

Do you have a SQL Statement that retrieves unique client id's from Oracle?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientID FROM SCHEMA.SALES
```

Comment: As I mentioned above the SSIS String Variable would be over 4000 characters with building the IN string.